# Extracting data from an array of Object

Tags: reactjs, use-state, array.prototype.map

I have an array of objects that looks something like this:

`0: {observationId: 39986776, patientId: 3376, type: "painLevel", diastolicValue: null, systolicValue: null, …} 1: {observationId: 39970831, patientId: 3376, type: "bloodPressure", diastolicValue: 75, systolicValue: 132, …} 2: {observationId: 39970832, patientId: 3376, type: "heartrate", diastolicValue: null, systolicValue: null, …}`

Each of these object has a set of information that I need to get into a component. I was trying to map over the object to set a state variable to each object depending on the type held inside however I am having trouble getting them to be set this is what ive tried to do:

```
const PCCVitals = ({PCCObservations}) => {
  const [painLevel, setPainLevel] = useState({});
  const [BP, setBP] = useState({})
  const [OS, setOS] = useState({})
  const [heartRate, setHeartRate] = useState({})
  const [respiration, setRespiration] = useState({})
  const [weight, setWeight] = useState({})
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    observationMap
  }, [PCCObservations])
  
  const observationMap = () => {

  PCCObservations.map(item => {
    if(item.type === "painLevel"){
      setPainLevel(item)
    } if(item.type === "bloodPressure"){
      setBP(item)
    } if(item.type === "heartrate"){
      setHeartRate(item)
    } if(item.type === "oxygenSaturation" ){
      setOS(item)
    } if (item.type === "respirations"){
      setRespiration(item)
    } if(item.type === "weight"){
      setWeight(item)
    } if(item.type === "temperature"){
      setTemp(item)
    }
  })
}

  console.log(temp, "OBS PROPS")
  return(
    <>
    <ul>
      <li>{`Temperature - ${temp.value}${temp.unit}`}</li>
    </ul>
    </>
  )
 

}
```

My thinking here is if I take in the PCCObservations prop and map over it checking if the item.type is equal to the type I'm looking for then i should be able to set the state to that object. This implementation is not working... could someone shed some light on why its not working and how I can fix it to behave the way I want?

Comment: You could push the matching items into an array then outside of the `map()` set the items into their respective states. But you would need 7 arrays for your purpose and maybe there is a better way to do this. Also I think you forgot to call `observationMap()` in the `useEffect`.

Comment: Does the `PCCObservations` always have a single object for a type?

Comment: Yes theres always an object for each type for example an object for `painLevel` and an object for `bloodPressure` each object contains specific values for these types.

Comment: It's not clear what the ultimate goal is. How are you trying to display this information?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having multiple `useState`s you can maintain a single state that has everything in `PCCObservations`:

```
const getInitialState = someObvs => {
  return someObvs.reduce((acc, obs) => {
    acc[obs.type] = obs;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

const PCCVitals = ({ PCCObservations }) => {

    const [observations, setObservations] = useState(getInitialState(PCCObservations));

    // ...

    return <>{observations.painLevel.patientId}</>;
};
```

Now the `observations` state will look like:

```
 {
    painLevel: {
        observationId: 39986776,
        patientId: 3376,
        type: 'painLevel',
        diastolicValue: null,
        systolicValue: null,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
};
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hvahyc) implementing the above.

Comment: This didnt work for me the `observations` are staying as undefined. Can you explain what the line  `acc[obs.type] = obs;` is doing?

Comment: @CourtneyJ - It will create an object whose keys are `painLevel` etc. and values are the corresponding objects. If `observations` is undefined then `PCCObservations` might not have the objects it should have. I added a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hvahyc) that implements my suggestion to the answer, check that.